# Python mmap return Invalid argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, mmap

I tried to use `mmap` in Python

```
import mmap
import sys
f = open(sys.argv[1])
off = int(sys.argv[2])
mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(),length=0,access=mmap.ACCESS_READ,offset=off )
```

When off =0 that works fine .

But when off equal to any number (100 for example) I got `OSError: [ERROR 22] Invalid argument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offset must be a multiple of mmap.ALLOCATIONGRANULARITY but cannot be larger than the file size

Comment: What can I do if I want to mmap file by offset of 100 bytes ?

Comment: Just don't use the first 100 bytes?

Comment: @vtable Bear in mind that mmap.mmap supports *seek()*